# Cypress spy not being called

Tags: angular, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am rying to assert that a mocked service method is called from my component. This is the relevant typescript code for the class:

```
export class EditProfileCardComponent {

  test = 'test'

  constructor(private messageHandlingService: MessageHandlingService) {}

  onFileSelected(event: any) {  
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
    if(file.type != ValidFileTypes.JPG && file.type != ValidFileTypes.PNG) {
      this.test = "passed"; // this correctly sets the value to 'passed'
      this.displayInvalidFileTypeMessage();
    } else {
      // Some other logic...
    }
  }

 private displayInvalidFileTypeMessage() {
    this.messageHandlingService.displayMessage({
      message: "File selected must be JPEG or PNG file",
      action: SnackbarAction.Close,
      classType: SnackbarClassType.Error,
      duration: SnackbarDuration.Medium
    });
  }

}
```

This is the relevant html:

```
<p data-cy="test">{{test}}</p>
<input
   type="file"
   class="d-none"
   data-cy="file-input"
   accept=".png, .jpg"
   (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
   #fileUpload>
```

Here is my test:

```
 const messageHandlingService = {
    displayMessage: (snackBarItem: SnackBarItem) => {
      return null;
    }
  }

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(EditProfileCardComponent, setupCypressConfig<EditProfileCardComponent>({
      providers: [
        {provide: MessageHandlingService, useValue: messageHandlingService}
      ]
    }));
  });

it("onFileSelected method should call display message method in messageHandlingService when invalid file type is selected", () => {
    cy.spy(messageHandlingService, 'displayMessage');
    cy.get(elementBindings.fileInput).selectFile('cypress/fixtures/incorrect file type.webp', { force: true });
    cy.wait(1000); 

    //1st assertion (THIS PASSES)
    cy.get('[data-cy="test"]').should('have.text', 'passed');

    //2nd assertion (THIS FAILS)
    expect(messageHandlingService.displayMessage).to.be.calledOnceWithExactly({
      message: "File selected must be JPEG or PNG file",
      action: SnackbarAction.Close,
      classType: SnackbarClassType.Error,
      duration: SnackbarDuration.Medium
    });
  });
```

The 2nd assertion in my test is failing with the message:

> AssertionError: expected displayMessage to have been called exactly once with exact arguments Object{4}, but it was never called

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here as it seems like I have mocked the service correctly and also spied on the method correctly?

Here is the actual `messageHandlingService` for reference:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { SnackBarItem } from '../models/snackbar-item';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessageHandlingService {

  constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar) { }

  private displayNewMessage = new Subject<SnackBarItem>();

  newMessageReceived$ = this.displayNewMessage.pipe(
    tap(snackBarItem => this.displayMessage(snackBarItem))
  ).subscribe();

  onDisplayNewMessage(snackBarItem: SnackBarItem) {
    this.displayNewMessage.next(snackBarItem);
  }

  displayMessage(snackBarItem: SnackBarItem) {    
    this.snackbar.open(snackBarItem.message, snackBarItem.action, {
      panelClass: [snackBarItem.classType],
      duration: snackBarItem.duration,
      horizontalPosition: 'end'
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set up the spy before using it.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.spy(messageHandlingService, 'displayMessage')
  cy.mount(EditProfileCardComponent, ...
});
```

It's looks like the mounting process gets a reference to the original `displayMessage` that is set up in the mock service `messageHandlingService`, **before** the mock can wrap the method.

---

You could probably also set the spy directly in the mock service, something like

```js
const stub = Cypress.stub()
stub.withArgs({
  message: 'File selected must be JPEG or PNG file'   // tailor return to the args
}).returns(null)  

// or

stub.returns(null)                           // always returns null 

const messageHandlingService = {
  displayMessage: stub()
}
```